# How would I create this in an android app?

Tags: android, mobile, gridview

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Zt5ftxe.png]

I'm trying to re-create this in an android app but I don't know where to start.
I want the icons to be clickable and to lead to a different screen. Does GridLayout do this?

I followed a tutorial but it only dealt with images that don't lead to a separate screen.

Comment: you could google  a little on imagebuttons and get it done :) . happy coding. thats a lil hint that could help

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something more like a `DashBoard`.
In a Dashboard you can give the user a series of choice to select from in your main screen.

Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/) out ...
it will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

Using Gridview it can be done easily.you can achieve to call separate screen using gridview listner method ItemClick

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id)
 {

      //call Intent based on position

  }

});
```

see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Visually, you can have this structure with a GridLayout, yes.

If you want your icons to be clickable, you have to do a `setOnItemClickListener()` on each element of your GridLayout. To do this, it would be really good to create an Adapter which extends the `BaseAdapter` and set it to your `GridLayout`.

This tutorial is really well explained IMO to do what you want : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes Grid Layout is possible you can check this link for the same :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Other than this you can simply have Buttons on the linear layout and do the following task.:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
GridView oGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.services_gv);
oGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent oIntent = new Intent(YourcurrentActivity.this, NewActivityName.class);
            startActivity(oIntent);



        }
    });
```

And in the android manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="NewActivityName"
         >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridView` as follows:

**1. grid_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

    </GridView>
```

**2. ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6            
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

**3. AndroidGridLayoutActivity**

```
public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGridLayoutActivity.this, "" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Following are the links for good `GridView` tutorials:

1. [**AndroidHive**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)
2. [**Mkyong**](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 6 images in a layout and set click listener to them

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/resultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```